# How can I rename items using /replaceitem in MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am attempting to rename a cobblestone using the below command, and it is not working:

```
/replaceitem block ~ ~1 ~ slot.container 0 cobblestone 31 0 {display:{name:CobbLELstone
```

I have double checked - it is the right block. I have looked at other sources and have found nothing helpful. The error I'm getting is:

> Syntax error: Unexpected "": at "bbLELstone>><<"

Can you help explain what I have done wrong?

Here are some screenshots in case they help:

[image: Command Block Window with command and error]

[image: Command Block code window only]

Comment: I recommend you to look up command tutorials and the wiki pages for command and NBT syntax. I'm not too familiar with PE commands, but I can already spot at least 4 syntax errors. There should also be an error message somewhere, telling you a bit about what's wrong.

Comment: Your synax is incorrect, at least for pc. Did you try replaceitem block ~ ~1 ~ container.slot_0 cobblestone{display:{Name:"\"Cobblestone\""}} 31? Also are you targeting the correct block?

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe that you can rename things using nbt in Minecraft Bedrock Edition.
However, you could try using clone to achieve the same affect:
Put

`/clone ~ ~1 ~ ~ ~1 ~ ~ ~2 ~`

in a repeating always active command block. Put 31 cobblestone renamed “CobbLELstone” in the first chest (the one that is 1 block above the command block).
[image: chests]
[image: command block photo]

Answer (score -1):

You forgot the end curly bracket: `}`